# How to iterate over a set of 2 lists and display all lines in HTML?

Tags: python, html

I have a a set of 2 lists like so:

```
'[52.04061648544843, -0.6655072691644374] -> [52.4967, -1.90425]'
'[52.04061648544843, -0.6655072691644374] -> [52.4967, -1.90425]'
'[54.89272380289834, -2.8951219798364622] -> [57.63161, -3.11041]'
```

But when i try to render them in html i get only the first line showing in browser:

```
 {'[52.04061648544843, -0.6655072691644374] -> [52.4967, -1.90425]'}
```

How can i show all the lines of the lists?

Python file:

```
def dispatch_data(request):

    for d in d_site_customer_ids:
        data =  '[%s, %s] -> [%s, %s]' % (d['site'].latitude, 
            d['site'].longitude, d['customer'].latitude, d['customer'].longitude)
        
        #print(data)
    
    return render(request, 'dashboard/charts/dispatch.html', {'data':data})
```

I am rendering the data in html like so but it only returns the first line of the data:

```
<head>

</head>

<body>
    Hello
    {{ data }}


</body>
```

Thanks for any help!

SOLUTION:

I FIGURED IT OUT!!

I have to iterate through the lists in my html file like so:

```
<head>
    <!-- Custom styles for this page -->

</head>

<body>
    Hello
    {% for i in data %}
    {{ data }}
    {% endfor %}


</body>
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a dictionary of lists. Each line is a set containing a single string. Dictionaries look like `{key1: value1, key2: value2, ...}`

Comment: hmmm i think you are right!  there is no key so it must not be a dictionary! but a string of lists as you say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over the items like this( instead of you `for` block):

```
data =  [{'[%s, %s] -> [%s, %s]' % (d['site'].latitude, d['site'].longitude, d['customer'].latitude, d['customer'].longitude)} for d in d_site_customer_ids]
```

the problem in your code is that in each iteration of your loop you are replaceing previous data with the current data (`data = ...`).

the key is to use list of keep all of your dictionaries, other wise you should create a custom dictionary to keep all of them in seprated keys. but I strongly recommend you to use `list` for this purpose.

Comment: thanks for the comment. If i uncomment the ```print(data)``` then it prints all of the lines of the dictionary of lists. but when i try to render the data context in html then it only prints 1 line... thanks for the ```list``` not sure how i'll use it but i'll do some research! Would this mean i need to append the lists of strings?

Comment: Hi @Mehrad, thanks for providing a solution, it was noted by another poster than i do not infact have a dictionary as there no keys.. but this is a set of 2 lists? is true? thanks

Comment: Also what is the difference/benefits of your for loop and my for block?